# c# отличие StreamReader от FileStream

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Не могу понять, почему при

```
private static GoogleCredential? _credential;
private static readonly string[] _scopes = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets};

private static GoogleCredential GetCredential()
        {
            var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("client_secrets.json"));

            _credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream.ReadToEnd()).CreateScoped(_scopes);
            return _credential;
        }
```

получаю ошибку

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
> 'System.IO.Stream'

Хотя, при использовании аналогичного FileStream такой ошибки нет:

```
var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

_credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(_scopes);
```

Также код работает, если не создавать поток, а просто указать метод FromFile и указать json файл напрямую (я так понимаю, в таком случае поток создается внутри метода?):

```
_credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("client_secrets.json").CreateScoped(_scopes);
```

Comment: А вы понимаете тот код, что написали? Вот у вас есть метод `.FromStream()`, что дословно означает "Из потока", так зачем тогда вам `StreamReader` - это не поток, это "читалка" потока, у которой вы вызываете `.ReadToEnd()`, которая возвращает вам строку (`string`). Является строка `Stream`? Нет. Ну тогда почему вы думаете, что этот код должен работать? Поток вам дает `.OpenRead()`, вот его и используйте в первом варианте. `поток создается внутри метода?` - зависит от реализации метода. Если файл небольшой, то можно и простым `File.ReadAllText()` все прочитать, без потоков. Но скорей всего да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamReader` - это обертка над `Stream`, базовый класс для `StreamReader` является `TextReader` и предназначен он для чтения потока как текстовых данных, название говорит само за себя.

`Stream` же предназначен для работы с двоичными потоками данных, в этом и разница. Чтобы обратиться к двоичному потоку внутри `StreamReader`, нужно использовать свойство `TextReader.BaseStream`, для вашего случая `stream.BaseStream`.

Напротив `FileStream` это как раз наследник от того самого `Stream`. Другими словами, это разные классы, и задачи решают они разные, не стоит их путать.

Не стоит так же забывать про `IDisposable`, в этом случае код будет выглядеть как-то так.

```
private static GoogleCredential GetCredential()
{
    using Stream stream = new File.OpenRead("client_secrets.json");

    return GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(_scopes);
}
```

А `GoogleCredential.FromFile("client_secrets.json")` действительно сам создает поток внутри себя.

Так что такой вариант эквивалентен по поведению, но более лаконичен:

```
private static GoogleCredential GetCredential()
{
    return GoogleCredential.FromFile("client_secrets.json").CreateScoped(_scopes);
}
```

`.FromStream` больше полезен, когда данные не в файле, а где-то в другом месте, либо на момент написания кода неизвестно, где именно:

```
private static GoogleCredential GetCredential(Stream stream)
{
    return GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(_scopes);
}
```

Работа по созданию потока здесь за пределами метода. А потом может быть создан не обязательно из файла.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю по поводу IDisposable - что вместо using можно просто вызвать метод stream.Close() ?

Comment: @HumbleNewbie правильно, но все-таки это не одно и то же. Чтобы узнать разницу, познакомьтесь с `using` и конструкцией `try-finally`.